# Buttons are not showing up after being hidden in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of buttons, some shown some hidden. When the shown buttons are clicked, they should get hidden and a select few of the hidden buttons should get shown. Unfortunately, only the shown buttons are becoming hidden. The hidden buttons don't appear.

I have tried different display types for the buttons, but I actually no nothing of html, CSS, or Javascript to know what I am doing or if what I am doing changes anything.

html:

```js
hideGenres();

function proudCondfidentResults() {
  hideFeelings();
  showIndustrialGothicButton();
  showMetalButton();
}

function powerfulPumpedResults() {
  hideFeelings();
}

function showIndustrialGothicButton() {
  document.getElementById("industrialGothic").style.display = "block";
}

function showMetalButton() {
  document.getElementById("metal").style.display = "block";
}

function hideFeelings() {
  document.getElementById("feelingButtons").style.display = "none";
}

function hideGenres() {
  document.getElementById("genreButtons").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
button {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #279;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #38a;
}
```

```html
<div id="feelingButtons">
  <button id="proudConfident" onclick="proudCondfidentResults()">Proud/Confident</button>
  <button id="powerfulPumped" onclick="powerfulPumpedResults()">Powerful/Pumped</button>
</div>

<div id="genreButtons">
  <button id="industrialGothic" onclick="industrialGothicLink()">Industrial/Gothic</button>
  <button id="metal" onclick="metalLink()">Metal</button>
</div>
```

When the `Proud/Confident` button is clicked I expect to have the `Proud/Confident` and `Powerful/Pumped` buttons disappear and for the `Industrial/Gothic` and `Metal` buttons to appear. What happens currently is the `Proud/Confident` and `Powerful/Pumped` buttons disappears, but the `Industrial/Gothic` and `Metal` buttons stay hidden. How do you make it so that the `Industrial/Gothic` and `Metal` buttons are shown?

Comment: You hide the container (`genreButtons`), and never re-show it.

Comment: How would I rectify it? Attempting to show the container in `hidefeelings()` like @brk said does not fix the issue as I only want a select few buttons within `genreButtons` to be shown, yet all are shown with his/her implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display style of `genreButtons` div

```js
hideGenres();

function proudCondfidentResults() {
  hideFeelings();
  industrialGothicLink();
  showMetalButton();
}

function powerfulPumpedResults() {
  hideFeelings();
}

function industrialGothicLink() {
  document.getElementById("industrialGothic").style.display = "block";
}

function showMetalButton() {
  document.getElementById("metal").style.display = "block";
}

function hideFeelings() {
  document.getElementById("feelingButtons").style.display = "none";
  //changed here
  document.getElementById("genreButtons").style.display = "block";
}

function hideGenres() {
  document.getElementById("genreButtons").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
button {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #279;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #38a;
}
```

```html
<div id="feelingButtons">
  <button id="proudConfident" onclick="proudCondfidentResults()">Proud/Confident</button>
  <button id="powerfulPumped" onclick="powerfulPumpedResults()">Powerful/Pumped</button>
</div>

<div id="genreButtons">
  <button id="industrialGothic" onclick="industrialGothicLink()">Industrial/Gothic</button>
  <button id="metal" onclick="metalLink()">Metal</button>
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. However, if I do that than all my genre buttons show. I only want a few to show. Is there away to allow only a few to show while still using the `div` strategy or do I have to individually hide each genre button?

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the Genre Buttons div by default via CSS (display:none). Once Proud/Confident are clicked, the genreButtons div will show as desired. This way, all the elements within the genre's div will toggle together.

```
<html><body>
<style>
    button {
        font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        background-color: #279;
        color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 0.5%;
        margin-bottom: 0.5%;
        display: block;
        height: 20%;
        width: 49%;
        float: left;
    }

    button:hover {
        background-color: #38a;
    }

    #genreButtons {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    hideGenres();

    function proudCondfidentResults() {
        hideFeelings();
        showIndustrialGothicButton();
        showMetalButton();
    }

    function powerfulPumpedResults() {
        hideFeelings();
    }

    function showIndustrialGothicButton() {
        document.getElementById("industrialGothic").style.display = "block";
    }

    function showMetalButton() {
        document.getElementById("genreButtons").style.display = "block";
    }

    function hideFeelings() {
        document.getElementById("feelingButtons").style.display = "none";
    }

    function hideGenres() {
        document.getElementById("genreButtons").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<div id="feelingButtons">
    <button id="proudConfident" onclick="proudCondfidentResults()">Proud/Confident</button>
    <button id="powerfulPumped" onclick="powerfulPumpedResults()">Powerful/Pumped</button>
</div>

<div id="genreButtons">
    <button id="industrialGothic" onclick="industrialGothicLink()">Industrial/Gothic</button>
    <button id="metal" onclick="metalLink()">Metal</button>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. I added the 
`#genreButtons {
        display: none;
    }` and I removed the `hideGenres()` from the Javascript so to not interfere as others have said, but still the genreButtons `div` is not showing.